# Tkinter Root Window Disappeared after Withdraw()

Tags: python, tkinter, window

I am writing a program that opens a file using the file browser and stores it as a path in a variable. I want to hide the root window until after the file path has been selected. However after I call the root.withdraw() method

I have tried calling root.deiconify() after the file path method and also root.iconify() I have also tried using the Toplevel method however it seems the window has completely vanished from the screen and the taskbar.

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.winfo_toplevel()
root.withdraw()

filePath = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="~/", title="Select file")

root.update()

fileSize = os.path.getsize(filePath)
print("File selected: " + filePath)
print("\nfile is: " + str(fileSize) + " bytes\n")

#.............................................................
root.deiconify()
button1 = (root, text="SHA256", command=SHA256(filePath))
button1.pack()

fileType = input("specify checksum type: " + "(ex. md5, sha1, sha256)" + "\n")

if fileType.lower() == "md5":
    message = MD5(filePath)
    print("MD5:\n" + message + "\n")
elif fileType.lower() == "sha256":
    message = SHA256(filePath)
    print("SHA256:\n" + message + "\n")
elif fileType.lower() == "sha1":
    message = SHA1(filePath)
    print("SHA1:\n" + message + "\n")

elif fileType.lower() not in hashTypes:
    print("Invalid file type \n\n")
```

No errors are being shown the root window has simply vanished and cannot be recalled into view.

Comment: Is this all of the code? I don't see where you're calling `mainloop` anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those two together:

```
root.update()
root.deiconify()
```

are the correct way to bring back root after `withdraw` call. You probably have a problem that your program don't have a main loop- bind some button to root.destroy and call root.mainloop() at the end.